# when I use ElementPath in SSRS when getting data from Web Service I get no results

Tags: asp.net, web-services, reporting-services, web, ssrs-2008

I have created a web service that returns a dataset that I manually fill with data.  When I start the service and get results this is the XML that I get returned.

```
<DataSet>
  <xs:schema id="Results">
    <xs:element name="Results" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="BillInfo">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="AccountType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="AccountNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="AmountDue" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="BillDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="DaysTilDue" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>

  <diffgr:diffgram>
    <Results>
      <BillInfo diffgr:id="BillInfo1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <AccountType>PP</AccountType>
        <AccountNumber>1</AccountNumber>
        <AmountDue>307.6500</AmountDue>
        <BillDescription>Bill Number 20121</BillDescription>
        <DaysTilDue>-362</DaysTilDue>
      </BillInfo>
      <BillInfo diffgr:id="BillInfo2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <AccountType>PP</AccountType>
        <AccountNumber>1</AccountNumber>
        <AmountDue>307.6500</AmountDue>
        <BillDescription>Bill Number 20121</BillDescription>
        <DaysTilDue>-362</DaysTilDue>
      </BillInfo>
    </Results>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

If I set no element path and try to set my SSRS DataSet equal to the results I get the schema returned as the information.  Anytime I try to enter an elementpath I get no results.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Below I show the query I am using including the ElementPath to load my SSRS DataSet

```
<Query>
    <SoapAction>http://tempuri.org/GetBillData</SoapAction>
    <Method Namespace="http://tempuri.org/" Name="GetBillData" />
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Name="PartyID">
          <DefaultValue>0</DefaultValue>
        </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
    <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True"> DataSet {}/ diffgram {}/ Results {}/BillInfo</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

If anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong I would love to hear it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the "ElementPath" must start something like this:
GetBillDataResponse{}/GetBillDataResult{}/DataSet{}/diffgram{}...
[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can help you find out about the datastructure.

Answer (score 2):

This would make it work for sure. All matters is the correct Syntax

```
<Query>
<Method Name="GetBillData" Namespace="http://tempuri.org/" >
<Parameters>
<Parameter Name="PartyID">
<DefaultValue>0</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
</Parameters>
</Method>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">
GetBillDataResponse/GetBillDataResult/diffgram/Results/BillInfo
</ElementPath>
<SoapAction>http://tempuri.org/GetBillData</SoapAction>
</Query>
```